# Retrieving Id elasticbeanstalk (EBS) environment in the terminal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I get the Id of my elasticbeanstalk (EBS) environment in the terminal?

This command returns an object in the terminal with some properties for the environment:
`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names my-env`

Is it possible to get only the `EnvironmentId` from that object in the terminal?

```json
{
    "Environments": [
        {
            "ApplicationName": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx", 
            "EnvironmentName": "my-env", 
            "VersionLabel": "Initial Version", 
            "Status": "Ready", 
            "EnvironmentArn": "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1:xxxxxxx:environment/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx/my-env", 
            "EnvironmentLinks": [], 
            "PlatformArn": "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-central-1::platform/Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.0", 
            "EndpointURL": "awseb-e-2-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com", 
            "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.11.0 running Multi-container Docker 18.03.1-ce (Generic)", 
            "EnvironmentId": "e-1234567", 
            "CNAME": "my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com", 
            "AbortableOperationInProgress": false, 
            "Tier": {
                "Version": "1.0", 
                "Type": "Standard", 
                "Name": "WebServer"
            }, 
            "Health": "Green", 
            "DateUpdated": "2018-07-12T06:10:17.056Z", 
            "DateCreated": "2018-07-11T20:03:26.970Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, the result that I'm expecting in my terminal to appear is `e-1234567`

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use the AWS CLI for this, you would need to filter the output of `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names my-env` using a tool such as `grep`. One possible (by no means optimal/concise) solution :

   ```
   aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names my-env | grep EnvironmentId | grep -Eo "e-[A-Za-z0-9_]+"
   ```
2. The better solution is to use an AWS SDK such as [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) (the Python AWS SDK).

   ```py
   import boto3


   elasticbeanstalk = boto3.client(
       'elasticbeanstalk',
       region_name='us-west-2'
   )
   response = elasticbeanstalk.describe_environments(
       EnvironmentNames=['my-env']
   )

   if response['Environments']:
       print(response['Environments'][0]['EnvironmentId'])
   ```

AWS SDKs are available in other popular languages such as Go, Java, Ruby, JavaScript, PHP as well.